# The <K> class in a groupByKey(...) has a Map among its members. The groupByKey operation fails on an "un-comparable" problem

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a class `Entreprise` that have primives data types and a Map on another class : `Etablissement` that is only made of primitive data types.

```java
public class Entreprise implements Comparable<Entreprise> {
   /** Liste des établissements de l'entreprise. */
   private Map<String, Etablissement> etablissements = new HashMap<>();

   /** Sigle de l'entreprise */
   private String sigle;

   /** Nom de naissance */
   private String nomNaissance;

   /** Nom d'usage */
   private String nomUsage;
 ...
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Entreprise o) {
      return getSiren().compareTo(o.getSiren());
   }
}
```

In an `EntrepriseDataset` I created this schema :

```java
public StructType schemaEntreprise() {
   StructType schema = new StructType()
      .add("sigle", StringType, true)
      .add("nomNaissance", StringType, true)
      .add("nomUsage", StringType, true)
       ...

   // Ajouter au Dataset des entreprises la liaison avec les établissements.
   MapType mapEtablissements = new MapType(StringType, this.datasetEtablissement.schemaEtablissement(), true);
   StructField etablissements = new StructField("etablissements", mapEtablissements, true, Metadata.empty());
   schema.add(etablissements);

  return schema;
}
```

I can do convenients `joinWith` such as :

```java
Dataset<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> ds = dsEntreprises
    .joinWith(dsEtablissements,
    dsEntreprises.col("siren").equalTo(dsEtablissements.col("siren")), "inner");
```

It's the beginning of some operations that should lead me to a Dataset of `Entreprise` objects having their `Etablissement` objects in their maps

```
Enterprise : {{834935512, Activité principale : 68.20A (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : null (null, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : Jan 26, 2018, historisation débutée le Dec 26, 2017, nombre de périodes sans changement : 1}, nombre d'établissements : 1, catégorie entreprise : null (null), catégorie juridique : 1000, n° répertoire national des associations : null, Economie Sociale et Solidaire : null, NIC de l'établissement siège : 00014, sigle : null, dénomination de l'entreprise : {18}, dénominations usuelles 1 : null, 2 :{19}, 3 : {20}, 4 : {21} , Nom de naissance : LOHIER, Nom d'usage : null, prénom usuel : ROGER, autres prénoms : ROGER, pseudonyme : null, sexe : M, purgée : null, date de création : Dec 26, 2017}
Etablishment : {{83493551200014, Activité principale : 68.20A (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : null (null, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : Jan 26, 2018, historisation débutée le Dec 26, 2017, nombre de périodes sans changement : 1}, activité au registre des métiers : null, date de création de l'établissement : 2017-12-26, établissement siège : false, dénomination de l'établissement : null, enseigne 1 : null, 2 : null, 3 : null, adresses : {anomalies : [], annulé logiquement : false, distribution spéciale : null, numéro dans la voie : 74, répétition : null, type de voie : BD, libellé de voie : DE LA PORTELETTE, complément d'adresse : 74-78, code postal : 80100, cedex : null - null, commune : 80001 - ABBEVILLE, commune étrangère : null, pays : null - null}}

Enterprise : {{178001111, Activité principale : 84.23Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : 41 (2016, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : Jan 17, 2019, historisation débutée le Jan 1, 2008, nombre de périodes sans changement : 5}, nombre d'établissements : 3, catégorie entreprise : ETI (2,016), catégorie juridique : 7171, n° répertoire national des associations : null, Economie Sociale et Solidaire : null, NIC de l'établissement siège : 00016, sigle : null, dénomination de l'entreprise : {18}, dénominations usuelles 1 : null, 2 :{19}, 3 : {20}, 4 : {21} , Nom de naissance : null, Nom d'usage : null, prénom usuel : null, autres prénoms : null, pseudonyme : null, sexe : null, purgée : null, date de création : Jan 1, 1978}
Etablishment : {{17800111100396, Activité principale : 84.23Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : 11 (2016, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : Sep 29, 2018, historisation débutée le Jan 1, 2008, nombre de périodes sans changement : 3}, activité au registre des métiers : null, date de création de l'établissement : 1983-01-01, établissement siège : false, dénomination de l'établissement : null, enseigne 1 : TRIBUNAL D'INSTANCE D'ABBEVILLE, 2 : null, 3 : null, adresses : {anomalies : [], annulé logiquement : false, distribution spéciale : BP A8, numéro dans la voie : 79, répétition : null, type de voie : RUE, libellé de voie : MARECHAL FOCH, complément d'adresse : null, code postal : 80100, cedex : 80103 - ABBEVILLE CEDEX, commune : 80001 - ABBEVILLE, commune étrangère : null, pays : null - null}}
Etablishment : {{17800111100743, Activité principale : 84.23Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : null (null, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : Sep 1, 2008, historisation débutée le Dec 25, 2007, nombre de périodes sans changement : 1}, activité au registre des métiers : null, date de création de l'établissement : 2007-12-25, établissement siège : false, dénomination de l'établissement : null, enseigne 1 : TRIBUNAL PARITAIRE BAUX RURAUX, 2 : null, 3 : null, adresses : {anomalies : [], annulé logiquement : false, distribution spéciale : BP 330, numéro dans la voie : 79, répétition : null, type de voie : RUE, libellé de voie : MARECHAL FOCH, complément d'adresse : null, code postal : 80100, cedex : 80103 - ABBEVILLE CEDEX, commune : 80001 - ABBEVILLE, commune étrangère : null, pays : null - null}}
Etablishment : {{17800111100503, Activité principale : 84.23Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : 02 (2016, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : Sep 29, 2018, historisation débutée le Jan 1, 2008, nombre de périodes sans changement : 3}, activité au registre des métiers : null, date de création de l'établissement : 1982-07-01, établissement siège : false, dénomination de l'établissement : null, enseigne 1 : CONSEIL DE PRUD'HOMMES D'ABBEVILLE, 2 : null, 3 : null, adresses : {anomalies : [], annulé logiquement : false, distribution spéciale : null, numéro dans la voie : 9, répétition : null, type de voie : AV, libellé de voie : DU GENERAL LECLERC, complément d'adresse : null, code postal : 80100, cedex : null - null, commune : 80001 - ABBEVILLE, commune étrangère : null, pays : null - null}}
```

But what is going wrong is that I cannot execute a `groupByKey` :

```java
KeyValueGroupedDataset<Entreprise, Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> dsK = 
ds.groupByKey((MapFunction<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>, Entreprise>) f -> {
      Entreprise entreprise = f._1();
      Etablissement etablissement = f._2();
      entreprise.ajouterEtablissement(etablissement);

      return entreprise;
  }, 
  Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class));

Dataset<Entreprise> dsEntreprisesAvecEtablissements = 
dsK.mapGroups(new MapGroupsFunction<Entreprise, Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>, Entreprise>() {
     @Override
     public Entreprise call(Entreprise key, Iterator<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> values) {
        while(values.hasNext()) {
           Etablissement etablissement = values.next()._2();
           key.ajouterEtablissement(etablissement);
        }

        return key;
      }
   },
   Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class));
```

That `groupByKey(...)` (or more accurately the first action taken on `dsEntreprisesAvecEtablissements` dataset) fails with a message :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot generate compare code for un-comparable type: map<string,struct<activiteArtisanRegistreDesMetiers:string,activitePrincipale:string,anneeValiditeEffectifSalarie:int,cedex:string,cedexSecondaire:string,codeCommune:string,codeCommuneSecondaire:string,codePaysEtranger:string,codePaysEtrangerSecondaire:string,codePostal:string,codePostalSecondaire:string,complementAdresse:string,complementAdresseSecondaire:string,dateCreationEtablissement:string,dateDebutHistorisation:string,dateDernierTraitement:string,denominationEtablissement:string,distributionSpeciale:string,distributionSpecialeSecondaire:string,enseigne1:string,enseigne2:string,enseigne3:string,indiceRepetition:string,indiceRepetitionSecondaire:string,libelleCedex:string,libelleCedexSecondaire:string,libelleVoie:string,libelleVoieSecondaire:string,nomCommune:string,nomCommuneSecondaire:string,nomPaysEtranger:string,nomPaysEtrangerSecondaire:string,nombrePeriodes:int,nomenclatureActivitePrincipale:string,numeroVoie:string,numeroVoieSecondaire:string,siege:boolean,siret:string,trancheEffectifSalarie:string,typeDeVoie:string,typeDeVoieSecondaire:string>>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodegenContext.genComp(CodeGenerator.scala:700) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.$anonfun$genComparisons$3(GenerateOrdering.scala:121) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
```

I find no other groupByKey method allowing to give a alternative comparison method, that the equals(Map) the groupByKey seems to execute here. It doesn't consider that my Java Pojo targets of `Encoders.bean(..)` are `Comparable`. So, eventually, I have to end with this clumsy code :

```java
Entreprises entreprises = new Entreprises();

List<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> tuples = ds.collectAsList();
Iterator<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> itTuples = tuples.iterator();

while(itTuples.hasNext()) {
   Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement> tuple = itTuples.next();
   Entreprise entreprise = entreprises.get(tuple._1().getSiren());
   Etablissement etablissement = tuple._2();

   if (entreprise == null) {
      entreprise = tuple._1();
      entreprises.add(entreprise);
   }

   entreprise.ajouterEtablissement(etablissement);
}

return entreprises;
```

But a better way might exist to solve my problem more nicely. What should I have done to have at the end of my operations a `Dataset<Entreprise>` where each `Entreprise` has a Map of their `Etablissement` on it ?

Comment: Could you share a bit more details? Why do you use `Function1` and not Java's specific `MapFunction` for grouping operations? 
Also, `groupByKey` returns `KeyValueGroupedDataset` with Entreprise as a key, not a Dataset.

Comment: I have added explanation on the result expected and changed the code with the Java function I tried also. I also reported the second operation I was excuting to achieve my results : after the `groupByKeys(...)` I was expecting one `mapGroups(...)` to give me my wished `Dataset<Entreprise>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark does not allow comparison of `MapType`. You can do things a bit differently.

The important thing regarding your code is the **key** for joining and grouping by. It is the same for both of these operations. This makes things much easier.

You can try one of the following:

- Changing the key from `Enterprise` to `siren: String`. And collecting all the `Etablissement` records in `mapGroups`. This may cause issues in case of duplicate keys in `Enterprise`.
- Group by `siren` in Etablissement stream before join, and collecting them in the `mapGroups` function. The resulting stream is joined with the `Enterprise` stream followed by a map.

**First Solution**

```
Dataset<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> ds = dsEntreprises
                .joinWith(dsEtablissements,
                        dsEntreprises.col("siren").equalTo(dsEtablissements.col("siren")), "inner");

        KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> dsK = ds.groupByKey((MapFunction<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>, String>)
                value -> value._1.siren, Encoders.STRING());

        dsK.mapGroups((MapGroupsFunction<String, Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>, Entreprise>) (key, values) -> {
            Entreprise e = null;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement> tuple = values.next();
                if (e == null) {
                    e = tuple._1;
                }

                e.ajouterEtablissement(tuple._2);
            }

            return e;
        }, Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class))
                .foreach((ForeachFunction<Entreprise>) x -> System.out.println(x));
```

**Second Solution**
This solution is better because it deals with the case of duplicate keys in enterprise gracefully. It will also be efficient because it will reduce the number of records which are going to be joined.

```
KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Etablissement> ets = dsEtablissements.groupByKey((MapFunction<Etablissement, String>) value -> value.siren, Encoders.STRING());

    Dataset<EtablissementList> etm = ets.mapGroups((MapGroupsFunction<String, Etablissement, EtablissementList>) (key, values) -> {
        Map<String, Etablissement> map = new HashMap<>();
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            Etablissement etablissement = values.next();
            map.put(etablissement.getId(), etablissement);
        }

        return new EtablissementList(map, key);
    }, Encoders.bean(EtablissementList.class));

    Dataset<Tuple2<Entreprise, EtablissementList>> dx = dsEntreprises.joinWith(etm, dsEntreprises.col("siren").equalTo(etm.col("siren")), "inner");
    Dataset<Entreprise> finalDs = dx.map((MapFunction<Tuple2<Entreprise, EtablissementList>, Entreprise>) value -> {
        value._1.etablissements = value._2.etablissements;
        return value._1;
    }, Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class));

    finalDs.foreach((ForeachFunction<Entreprise>) x -> System.out.println(x));
```

POJO

```
public static class EtablissementList {
        private Map<String, Etablissement> etablissements = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        private String siren;

        public EtablissementList() {
        }

        public EtablissementList(Map<String, Etablissement> etablissements, String siren) {
            this.etablissements = etablissements;
            this.siren = siren;
        }

        public Map<String, Etablissement> getEtablissements() {
            return etablissements;
        }

        public void setEtablissements(Map<String, Etablissement> etablissements) {
            this.etablissements = etablissements;
        }

        public String getSiren() {
            return siren;
        }

        public void setSiren(String siren) {
            this.siren = siren;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying your solutions. Solution 1 : doesn't work but it's not your fault : `Spark 2.4.3` ends Java in a core dump. `siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR) in StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy`, with a test of 50 rows only. `Spark` is in so bad shape that I am not sure its version `3.0.0.` will ever be released.

Comment: Solution 2 : Fails when I attempt to collect enterprises at the end of a test with an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 41`.

Comment: For me, both are working fine. 
Let's discuss more in detail. Please join: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198077/apache-spark-group-by-key-error

Comment: I managed to make working your first solution on a sample of 50 rows. But for the larger files (2 millions records) it fails with the `Spark` well known dance : "_I lost job result (77/100) and I restart the process, Then the (12/100) the other time and (89 and 25/100) the last time,_" The core dump that happens often is a `JDK 8` bug that `Spark` makes happening : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8205989. Therefore, I shall grant you the bounty because I feel that your solutions are the good ones, even if at the moment `Spark` is reluctant to execute them.