# a MapType causes an AnalysisException in Spark 3.x : Encoders.bean to an object containg a map<String, someClass> fails, that works fine in Spark 2.4

Tags: java, apache-spark

Attempting to migrate my *Java Spark* code from `2.4` to `3.x`, I have one dataset one that holds a `MapType`.

```java
/**
 * Renvoyer le schéma du Dataset.
 * @return Schema.
 */
public StructType schemaEntreprise() {
   StructType schema = new StructType()
      .add("siren", StringType, false)
      .add("statutDiffusionUniteLegale", StringType, true)
      .add("unitePurgeeUniteLegale", StringType, true )
      .add("dateCreationEntreprise", StringType, true)
      .add("sigle", StringType, true)
     
   /* ... and other fields mostly of String, Integer, Boolean type... */
   
   // Ajouter au Dataset des entreprises la liaison avec les établissements.
   MapType mapEtablissements = new MapType(StringType,
this.datasetEtablissement.schemaEtablissement(), true);
   StructField etablissements = new StructField("etablissements",
mapEtablissements, true, Metadata.empty());
   schema.add(etablissements);
   schema.add("libelleCategorieJuridique", StringType, true);
   schema.add("partition", StringType, true);
   
   return schema;
}
```

The `Dataset<Etablissement>` and the business objet `Etablissment` have only primitives types in them :

```java
public StructType schemaEtablissement() {
   return new StructType()
      .add("siren", StringType, false)
      .add("nic", StringType, false)
      .add("siret", StringType, false)
      .add("statutDiffusionEtablissement", StringType, true)
      .add("dateCreationEtablissement", StringType, true)
         
      .add("trancheEffectifSalarie", StringType, true)
   [...]
```

```java
public class Etablissement extends AbstractSirene<SIRET> implements Comparable<Etablissement> {
   /** Serial ID. */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 2451240618966775942L;
   
   /** Année et mois de création de l'établissement. */
   private String dateCreation;
   
   /** Qualité de siège ou non de l'établissement */
   private boolean siege;

   /** Enseigne 1 ou nom de l'exploitation */
   private String enseigne1;
   
   /** Enseigne 2 ou nom de l'exploitation */
   private String enseigne2;
   [...]
```

This `Entreprise` dataset works perfectly in *Spark 2.4.* but when used in *Spark 3.0.1* inside an operation, its analysis phase ends with an unclear message :

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: *Can't extract value from lambdavariable(MapObject, StringType, true, 376)*: need struct type but got string;`

---

EDIT : I add new information about my problem :
It's not a `spark.sql.legacy.allowHashOnMapType=true` missing problem. Adding it doesn't resolve it.

The problem happens when `Spark 3` attempts to perform a :
`Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class)` in order to create the enterprise objects, who have this class :

```java
public class Entreprise extends AbstractSirene<SIREN> implements Comparable<Entreprise> {
   /** Serial ID. */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 2451240618966775942L;
   
   /** Liste des établissements de l'entreprise. */
   private Map<String, Etablissement> etablissements = new HashMap<>();
   
   /** Sigle de l'entreprise */
   private String sigle;
   
   /** Nom de naissance */
   private String nomNaissance;

   [...]   
   /**
    * Renvoyer la liste des établissements de l'entreprise.
    * @return Liste des établissements.
    */
   public Map<String, Etablissement> getEtablissements() {
      return this.etablissements;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer la liste des établissements de l'entreprise.
    * @param etablissementsEntreprise Liste des établissements.
    */
   public void setEtablissements(Map<String, Etablissement> etablissementsEntreprise) {
      this.etablissements = etablissementsEntreprise;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le sigle (forme réduite de la raison sociale ou de la dénomination d'une personne morale ou d'un organisme public) (SIGLE).
    * @return Sigle. 
    */
   public String getSigle() {
      return this.sigle;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le sigle (forme réduite de la raison sociale ou de la dénomination d'une personne morale ou d'un organisme public) (SIGLE).
    * @param sigle Sigle. 
    */
   public void setSigle(String sigle) {
      this.sigle = sigle;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le nom de naissance pour une personne physique (NOM).
    * @return Nom de naissance pour une personne physique.
    */
   public String getNomNaissance() {
      return this.nomNaissance;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le nom de naissance pour une personne physique (NOM).
    * @param nom Nom de naissance pour une personne physique.
    */
   public void setNomNaissance(String nom) {
      this.nomNaissance = nom;
   }

   [...]
}
```

A debugging has shown me that Scala failed here :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from lambdavariable(MapObject, StringType, true, 32): need struct type but got string;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.apply(complexTypeExtractors.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$applyOrElse$170$$anonfun$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$172.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:3076)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$applyOrElse$170$$anonfun$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$172.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:3074)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$2(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:330)
[...]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$2(TreeNode.scala:416)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.$anonfun$iterator$3(MapLike.scala:257)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:331)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike.force$(TraversableViewLike.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$applyOrElse$170$$anonfun$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:3074)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$applyOrElse$170$$anonfun$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:3070)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChild$2(TreeNode.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$4(TreeNode.scala:427)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$2(TreeNode.scala:416)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.$anonfun$iterator$3(MapLike.scala:257)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:331)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike.force$(TraversableViewLike.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:314)
[...]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolveAndBind(ExpressionEncoder.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolvedEnc$lzycompute(Dataset.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$resolvedEnc(Dataset.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.as(Dataset.scala:475)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.entreprise.EntrepriseDataset.toDatasetEntreprise(EntrepriseDataset.java:320)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.entreprise.EntrepriseDataset.dsEntreprises(EntrepriseDataset.java:307)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.entreprise.EntrepriseDataset.collectEntreprisesEtEtablissements(EntrepriseDataset.java:366)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.entreprise.EntrepriseDatasetIT.entreprisesEtEtablissementsDeDouarnenez(EntrepriseDatasetIT.java:189)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)[...]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

and the `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.apply(complexTypeExtractors.scala` is this one, but I have no knowledge of Scala, and I don't know what it expect :

[image]

---

In the case everything is working fine (=> in `Spark 2.4.7`), the following unit test gives the results next to him :

```java
/**
* Obtention des entreprises et établissements de Douanenez.
* @throws TechniqueException si un incident survient.
*/
@Test
@DisplayName("Les entreprises et établissements de Douanenez.")
public void entreprisesEtEtablissementsDeDouarnenez() throws TechniqueException {
  Column douarnenez = col("codeCommune").equalTo("29046");
  
  Entreprises entreprises = 
    this.entrepriseDataset.collectEntreprisesEtEtablissements(this.session, 
    COG, ANNEE_SIRENE, true, true, null, douarnenez);
  
  LOGGER.info("{} entreprises ont été lues.", entreprises.size());
  
  for(Entreprise entreprise : entreprises) {
     LOGGER.info(entreprise.toString());
     entreprise.getEtablissements().values()
        .forEach(etablissement -> LOGGER.info("\t{}", etablissement.toString()));
  }
}
```

```
2287 entreprises ont été lues.
{{314551813, Activité principale : 56.30Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : 00 (2017, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : 24 juin 2019, historisation débutée le 1 janv. 2008, nombre de périodes sans changement : 3}, nombre d'établissements : 1, catégorie entreprise : PME (2 017), catégorie juridique : 1000, n° répertoire national des associations : null, Economie Sociale et Solidaire : null, NIC de l'établissement siège : 00012, sigle : null, dénomination de l'entreprise : {18}, dénominations usuelles 1 : HOTEL BAR LA RADE, 2 :{19}, 3 : {20}, 4 : {21} , Nom de naissance : HERAUD, Nom d'usage : HASCOET, prénom usuel : MICHELINE, autres prénoms : MICHELINE, pseudonyme : null, sexe : F, purgée : null, date de création : 1 janv. 1978}
    {{31455181300012, Activité principale : 56.30Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : 00 (2017, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : 24 juin 2019, historisation débutée le 1 janv. 2008, nombre de périodes sans changement : 3}, activité au registre des métiers : null, date de création de l'établissement : 1978-01-01, établissement siège : false, dénomination de l'établissement : null, enseigne 1 : null, 2 : null, 3 : null, adresses : {anomalies : [], annulé logiquement : false, distribution spéciale : null, numéro dans la voie : 31, répétition : null, type de voie : QUAI, libellé de voie : DU GRAND PORT, complément d'adresse : null, code postal : 29100, cedex : null - null, commune : 29046 - Douarnenez, commune étrangère : null, pays : null - null}}
{{484663224, Activité principale : 46.49Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : 02 (2017, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : 5 juil. 2020, historisation débutée le 31 déc. 2019, nombre de périodes sans changement : 4}, nombre d'établissements : 2, catégorie entreprise : PME (2 017), catégorie juridique : 5499, n° répertoire national des associations : null, Economie Sociale et Solidaire : null, NIC de l'établissement siège : 00018, sigle : null, dénomination de l'entreprise : {18}, dénominations usuelles 1 : null, 2 :{19}, 3 : {20}, 4 : {21} , Nom de naissance : null, Nom d'usage : null, prénom usuel : null, autres prénoms : null, pseudonyme : null, sexe : null, purgée : null, date de création : 5 oct. 2005}
    {{48466322400026, Activité principale : 33.15Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : null (null, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : 10 juil. 2014, historisation débutée le 1 janv. 2014, nombre de périodes sans changement : 1}, activité au registre des métiers : null, date de création de l'établissement : 2014-01-01, établissement siège : false, dénomination de l'établissement : null, enseigne 1 : MARINE SERVICE, 2 : null, 3 : null, adresses : {anomalies : [], annulé logiquement : false, distribution spéciale : null, numéro dans la voie : 3, répétition : null, type de voie : IMP, libellé de voie : DE PENN AR CREACH, complément d'adresse : null, code postal : 29100, cedex : null - null, commune : 29046 - Douarnenez, commune étrangère : null, pays : null - null}}
    {{48466322400018, Activité principale : 33.15Z (NAFRev2), effectif salarié : 02 (2017, employeur : null), active : null, dernier traitement : 5 juil. 2020, historisation débutée le 1 janv. 2008, nombre de périodes sans changement : 4}, activité au registre des métiers : null, date de création de l'établissement : 2005-10-05, établissement siège : false, dénomination de l'établissement : null, enseigne 1 : MARINE SERVICE, 2 : null, 3 : null, adresses : {anomalies : [], annulé logiquement : false, distribution spéciale : null, numéro dans la voie : null, répétition : null, type de voie : PL, libellé de voie : VICTOR SALEZ, complément d'adresse : null, code postal : 29100, cedex : null - null, commune : 29046 - Douarnenez, commune étrangère : null, pays : null - null}}
[...]
```

---

EDIT 2 : The collect method

```java
public Entreprises collectEntreprisesEtEtablissements(SparkSession session, int anneeCOG, int anneeSIRENE, boolean actifsSeulement, boolean communesValides, 
   Column conditionSurEntreprises, Column conditionSurEtablissements) throws TechniqueException {
   return collectEntreprisesEtEtablissements(dsEntreprises(session, anneeSIRENE, actifsSeulement, conditionSurEntreprises, Tri.CODE_COMMUNE), 
   this.datasetEtablissement.dsEtablissements(session, anneeCOG, anneeSIRENE, actifsSeulement, communesValides, conditionSurEtablissements));
}
```

where the `dsEnterprises(...)` dans `dsEtablissements(...)` methods converts `Dataset<Row>` to `Dataset<Entreprise>` or `Dataset<Etablissement>`.

```java
/**
  * Obtenir les entreprises liées à leur établissements.
  * @param dsEntreprises Dataset d'entreprises.
  * @param dsEtablissements Dataset d'établissements.
  * @return Entreprises alimentées avec leurs établissements.
  */
public Entreprises collectEntreprisesEtEtablissements(Dataset<Entreprise> dsEntreprises, Dataset<Etablissement> dsEtablissements) {
   Dataset<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> ds = dsEntreprises.joinWith(dsEtablissements, dsEntreprises.col("siren").equalTo(dsEtablissements.col("siren")), "inner");
   Entreprises entreprises = new Entreprises();
      
   List<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> tuples = ds.collectAsList();
   Iterator<Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement>> itTuples = tuples.iterator();
      
   while(itTuples.hasNext()) {
      Tuple2<Entreprise, Etablissement> tuple = itTuples.next();
      Entreprise entreprise = entreprises.get(tuple._1().getSiren());
      Etablissement etablissement = tuple._2();
         
      if (entreprise == null) {
         entreprise = tuple._1();
         entreprises.add(entreprise);
      }
         
      entreprise.ajouterEtablissement(etablissement);
   }
      
   return entreprises;
}
```

### My question : what is expecting the new Spark version ?

Comment: have you setup this spark property spark.sql.legacy.allowHashOnMapType ?

Comment: Hi Marc, can you design a minimal reproducible example (sample data + minimal code)?

Comment: No, I've checked but nothing minimal ! The whole problem requires at least two POJOs to be observed, datasets that have rather complex operations, and it's only at the end that the troubles happens. When the operation has to return its results.

Comment: @SKumar I've tried your solution but it isn't enough : the problem is still here.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Please, can you indicate how do the `schemaEtablissement` method and the `Etablissement` class look like?

Comment: @jccampanero I've added them (but the post is at it's limit of 30,000 characters). `Etablissement` is a normal POJO with only primitives types inside.

Comment: Hi @MarcLeBihan. Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for updating the answer. Yes, probably the `Etablissement` class has nothing to do with the error. Please, can you instead include the code of the method `collectEntreprisesEtEtablissements` and related functionality? I mean, the code that actually interact with Spark to obtain your information.

Comment: @jccampanero I've added it. I had to reduce the size of the stacktrace copied in the post to allow it to enter.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan
1) did yo follow migration guide - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html
2) could you provide mvp that catches problem

Comment: @user902383 Yes, but there's nothing about a new way to handle/use `MapType`. What is _mvp_ the abbreviation of ?

Comment: Thank you very much for updating the answer. @MarcLeBihan Is it the same `collectEntreprisesEtEtablissements` method that appears in the stack trace? It seems to have a different signature that the one presented in your test

Comment: @jccampanero Right sorry. There's another method upon it, with the same name, that comes as an helper, to convert `Dataset<Row>` either to `Dataset<Entreprise>` or `Dataset<Etablissement>`. I've added it.

Comment: Please, you do not need to sorry for anything ;) Thank you very much. And, how do the methods `toDatasetEntreprise` and `dsEntreprises` looks like? As you can see in the stack trace, when you create the dataset in `toDatasetEntreprise` is where the problem arises. Is there something special in these methods?

Comment: @jccampanero The problem exactly happens when these methods eventually call a classical : `dsRow.as(Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class))`, where dsRow is a `Dataset<Row>`. This is my problem. Because I have no clue about what `Encoders.bean(...)` is now expecting that changed from 2.4.7.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan minimum viable product, in this case smallest possible code that replicates this issue. if you share it, im happy to look at it later tonite

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I will try to reproduce the issue with the information you provided. @MarcLeBihan In any case, I realized that you posted a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079840/converting-a-row-to-an-ojbect-containing-a-map-fails-with-cant-extract-value-f). In that question the schema for `Enterprise` defines `etablissements` as a `map` with key and value of type `string`. Maybe it is not significant but according to your schema you are defining the value as an `struct`.

Comment: @jccampanero It's because my left hand don't know what right hand did few months ago, sometimes ! I removed the duplicate question, sorry !

Comment: @user902383 I the problem I'm facing isn't an easy one. The overall problem is that _Spark_ through _Datasets_ aren't able to reproduce a behavior that _RDD_ allowed that was _Returning a list of __A__ objects (each having a primary key __a__), where each having also a sublist of __B__ objects related to that key __a___. The whole subject has been studied in detail [in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443808/the-k-class-in-a-groupbykey-has-a-map-among-its-members-the-groupbykey-o) with no really definitive answer.

Comment: Hi @MarcLeBihan. Sorry for the late reply. Please, do not worry ;). I was unable to reproduce the issue. You indicated that you created and standard `Dataset<Row>` but, how do you obtained this dataset, reading a file, for instance? If that is the case, it is possible that this file include corrupt information? Do the test work properly if you include the following configuration property: `spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true`. Please, see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#ignore-corrupt-files

Comment: Perhaps, if you previously had a different schema, when you are trying to process the information now you are facing this error.

Comment: @jccampanero The data from the file have no problem. If I compile with `spark-core` and `spark-sql` `2.4.7` I receive my objects _Entreprise_ with their underlying _Etablissement_ inside. If I compile with version `3.0.1` I receive quickly the AnalysisException message. Because `Spark 3.0.1` doesn't agree anymore with the `MapType` I've put on `Entreprise` object. My question is "_What is expecting Spark on 3.0.1 ?_".

Comment: Yes @MarcLeBihan, I understand that, but it is the only thing that comes to my mind, I think there is no reason for the error, the code looks fine. Please, in any way, can you try the proposed flag?

Comment: I tried `spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true` but it doesn't help. The `AnalysisException` comes at the beginning, before _Spark_ attempts to read the file physically.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that @MarcLeBihan. It does not matter f the bounty has finished, I will try to reproduce the issue again. I hope to come back with a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a special issue. The problem is that no guide exists that show a sample of how mapping a `MapType` in an object with _Spark 3_. If such a sample existed I would just have to reproduce it, but there is none. I'm not even sure that this feature has been tested again, working, in _Spark 3_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [with the help of another question targeting a point specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621840/litnull-castmapstring-struct-isnt-accepted-how-to-cast-to-a-map-that-h/66629294) that the cause of my trouble is a line not shown here, affecting only the construction of the `Entreprise` object :

```java
Dataset<Row> ds = ...
   .withColumn("etablissements", lit(null).cast("map<string,string>"))
```

and causes a failure at `dataset.as(Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class))` : `Spark 2.x` didn't checked the type of the value at cast time, but started to do it in `3.x`, and it appeared that my declared value for that cast had a wrong type.

my `map<string,string>` should be a `map<string,Etablissement>` instead. But that it cannot exactly be written that way :

The solution is :

```java
StructType etablissementType = Encoders.bean(Etablissement.class).schema();

Dataset<Row> ds = ...
   .withColumn("etablissements", lit(null)
      .cast(DataTypes.createMapType(StringType, etablissementType)))
```