# lit(null).cast("map<string,struct>") isn't accepted. How to cast to a map that has an object for value?

Tags: java, apache-spark

An `Enterprise` object has for member a `Map` of `<String, Establishment>` where the string key is its french identifier (the *SIRET*). Therefore you might have a single enterprise, a bank, that has thousands of establishments in the country.

```java
public class Entreprise extends AbstractSirene<SIREN> implements Comparable<Entreprise> {
   /** Liste des établissements de l'entreprise. */
   private Map<String, Etablissement> etablissements = new HashMap<>();
  ...
}
```

When I initialize an enterprise I currently don't know the establishments it has, I need to set a null value in the related column of the Dataset that is used by a `row.as(Encoders.bean(Entreprise.class))`  to fill that `etablissements` member you see in the `Entreprise` class.

But I don't know how do declare the cast : `struct` is refused as a type for the value part of the map :

```java
Dataset<Row> ds = ...
   .withColumn("caractereEmployeur", col("caractereEmployeurUniteLegale").equalTo("O").cast(BooleanType))
            
   .withColumn("purgee", col("unitePurgeeUniteLegale").equalTo("O").cast(BooleanType))
   .withColumn("etablissements", lit(null).cast("map<string,struct>"))
```

with the message : "*Datatype struct is not supported*".

What appears to me strange, is that if I trick it and write :
`lit(null).cast("map<string,string>")`
instead (what I did (by mistake) in `Spark 2.4.x` but it worked well, misleading me during a long time),
it fails in `Spark 3.x` with a message : "*Can't extract value from lambdavariable(MapObject, StringType, true, 32): need struct type but got string*", meaning that it's truely a struct type that it is waiting for, for the value part of the map.

What is the proper way to do this casting?

Comment: A `struct` needs to have fields. e.g. you can define the type as `map<string,struct<field1:string,fields2:int>>`. You cannot define an untyped struct

Comment: @mck I understand better. But it's cumbersome because my `Etablissement` object has plenty of members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataTypes.createMapType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.html#createMapType-org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType-org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType-) to create a [DataType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.html) that represents a map. This datatype can then be used to [cast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#cast-org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType-) the `null` column to the required type.

```java
StructType etablissementType = Encoders.bean(Etablissement.class).schema();

Dataset<Row> ds = ...
    .withColumn("caractereEmployeur", col("caractereEmployeurUniteLegale").equalTo("O")
    .withColumn("purgee", col("unitePurgeeUniteLegale").equalTo("O")
    .withColumn("etablissements", lit(null)
            .cast(DataTypes.createMapType(StringType, etablissementType)));
```

The schema of the dataframe will be

```
root
 |-- [...]
 |-- caractereEmployeur: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- purgee: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- etablissements: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- attr1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attr2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attr3: string (nullable = true)
```

assuming `Etablissement` has three attributes called `attr1`, `attr2` and `attr3`.

By the way: you can omit the `cast(BooleanType)` in the other two columns. `equalTo` already returns a boolean column.

Comment: I'm impressed : it works very well ! It avoids me the alternative solution to create the `Dataset<Entreprise>` by the mean of a map function and a constructor with arguments. An alternative solution that is sometimes very useful for complex objects where `Encoders.bean(..)` might not be clever enough, but is longer to set.